# How can I find the sum with the pointers?

Tags: c

How can I fix that with pointers ? with *p ?
How can ı find the total of columns?
I want to choose which column ı chose and see the total of it.
lets say array is this:

```
2 6 9 
5 6 9 
4 8 4
2 6 0 
4 6 7
```

then here is my program fragment:

```
for(*p=0;p<size;p++)
sum=sum+*p;
printf("\n");
```

Comment: please show a [mre]. Please don't tag c++ in c questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pointers:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define Size(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x))

int main() {
    int array[][3] = {
        {2, 6, 9},
        {5, 6, 9}, 
        {4, 8, 4},
        {2, 6, 0},
        {4, 6, 7}
    };

    int selected_column;
    // Size(*array) will be 3, the number of columns, that is:
    //     sizeof(int[3]) / sizeof(int)
    printf("Select column (1 - %zu): ", Size(*array));
    if(scanf(" %d", &selected_column) != 1 ||
       selected_column < 1 || selected_column > Size(*array)) return 1;
    --selected_column; // make it zero-based

    int sum = 0;
    // Size(array) will be 5, the number of rows, that is:
    //     sizeof(int[5][3]) / sizeof(int[3])
    for(int(*p)[Size(*array)] = array, (*e)[Size(*array)] = p + Size(array);
        p != e; ++p) 
    {
        sum += (*p)[selected_column];
    }

    printf("col %d sum = %d\n", selected_column, sum);
}
```

A much simpler and idiomatic approach would be to iterate over he outer array (consisting of `int[3]`s):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define Size(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x))

int main() {
    int array[][3] = {
        {2, 6, 9},
        {5, 6, 9}, 
        {4, 8, 4},
        {2, 6, 0},
        {4, 6, 7}
    };
    
    int selected_column;
    printf("Select column (1 - %zu): ", Size(*array));
    if(scanf(" %d", &selected_column) != 1 ||
       selected_column < 1 || selected_column > Size(*array)) return 1;
    --selected_column;

    int sum = 0;

    for(int row = 0; row < Size(array); ++row) {
        sum += array[row][selected_column];
    }

    printf("col %d sum = %d\n", selected_column, sum);
}
```

Output from both versions:

```
col 0 sum = 17
```